# Sub multiplicative property of infinity norm is equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Let, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be $n \times n$ matricies. When is it true that,
$$||\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}||_{\infty} = ||\mathbf{A}||_{\infty}||\mathbf{B}||_{\infty}? $$

Or is it always true? Thanks.

Comment: What if $AB=0$ and $A,B$ non-zero?

Comment: You can also pick $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, B =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ to see that it is not always an equality.